# tkinter python : open new window and close the old one

Tags: python, tkinter

im not good in python and that is my code which is user click on button then the project.py will open and the old window will close. but the old window did not close. i already use root.destroy and still did not solve the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

def start_game():
    # Replace "game.py" with the filename of your game
    os.system("python project.py")
    root.withdraw() # hide the current window

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Welcome to Engg Catcher!")

start_button = tk.Button(root, text="Start Game", command=start_game)
start_button.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should call `root.withdraw()` (or `root.destroy()`) before `os.system(...)`.

Comment: Also, you can also move the ```os.system()``` call after the ```root.mainloop()``` call and call the ```root.quit()``` in the start_game().